# How do I implement foldr for this particular structure?

Tags: haskell

I am learning Haskell. I have a list that looks like this:

```
data TwoValueList a = Empty | Node a a (TwoValueList a)
```

I wish to make this `Foldable`, such that I might be able to do computations like:

```
sum (Node 0 1 (Node 2 3 Empty)) --should produce 6
```

If there were only one value, it would be easy:

```
data OneValueList = Empty | Node a (OneValueList a)
instance Foldable OneValueList where
  foldr f b Empty = b
  foldr f b (Node a rest) = f a (foldr f b rest)
```

However, if there are two values inside one node, I can't finegle the types because `f` takes `a` and `b`, but I must apply `f` to both `a`s inside of the `TwoValueList` and combine them somehow. Am I missing some other type constraint?

Thank you.

Comment: What's wrong with `foldr f b (Node a1 a2 rest) = f a1 (f a2 (foldr f b rest))`? Just think about how you would implement `toList`, and everything should follow.

Comment: Are you a real daikon radish?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```hs
data TwoValueList a = Empty | Node a a (TwoValueList a)

instance Foldable TwoValueList where
  foldr _ ini Empty = ini
  foldr f ini (Node x y xs) = f x $ f y $ foldr f ini xs
```

The way this works is that `foldr` calls itself recursively on recursive instances of `TwoValueList` that are embeded in each other up until it meets `Empty`. At that point it returns `ini` which is the initial value and the call stack comes up resolving all the function calls further above.

Comment: Thank you. I blanked out and forgot that if `x` and `y` are both `a`s, then `f y` must be a `b`, so `f` can be called with `x` and `f y` as arguments.

Answer (score 4):

I find it easier to just define the `foldMap` method instead:

```
data TwoValueList a = Empty | Node a a (TwoValueList a)

instance Foldable TwoValueList where
  foldMap _ Empty = mempty
  foldMap f (Node x y r) = f x <> f y <> foldMap f r
```

Answer (score 1):

Just call `f` twice and give one value to each call: `foldr f b (Node x1 x2 xs) = f x1 (f x2 (foldr f b xs))`.